# Populate column using single cell value from a different column with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to populate an entire date column in an Access database with a single date value for when the data was collected. The date value is contained in each table, but I want a separate field containing the date in each row. When I used this code it only populated the one row in my new field (sampling_date) where the date is located. The date is located in the sampling_info field on row 4

```
UPDATE table SET [sampling_date]=[sampling_info] WHERE [point]=4;
```

Thanks for any help,
Paul

Comment: *"I want a separate field with a row"* - hurts my brain

Comment: Sorry, Red. That did look funny now that you mention it. It made sense in my head...YIKES! What I want is a column containing the date for each point that was sampled (the point column).    What I have is a single cell that contains the date (numerous points were sampled on same date). Each table in my database refers to the points sampled on a specific date, and I eventually want to merge these into a single file but preserve the date value for each point.

Comment: I don't think it solves your question, but your SQL I think would be more correct if written `UPDATE t SET [sampling_date] = [sampling_info] FROM table t WHERE [point] = 4;`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like this is what you're after

```
UPDATE [table] SET sampling_date = DLookup("sampling_info","table","point=4")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly (and elegantly and beautifully...). Thanks so much Gord!